# How to make Flash add enough frames automatically for my mp3 import?

Tags: flash, mp3, flash-cs5, frames

I have a 30 minute mp3 I need to embed in an .fla so I can export as .mov for conversion to .fla.

I tried adding frames, but you can only add so many at a time. At 30 minutes, I had added the max frames (going to the rigth) about 15 times and it wasn't enough.

Is there a trick to automatically adding enough frames to cover the entire imported mp3 on the timeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A flash movie can have up to **16.000 frames**, if your mp3 is 30 minutes long there is no way you can embed it in your .fla (at 30 fps, which is a normal rate, you would need 54.000 frames, well beyond the limit). I guess you could **reduce the fps of your movie** to try to fit the entire .mp3, but you'd end up with a gigantic flash file, which might cause you problems.

So my advise would be to take a look at the [ActionScript class Sound](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/Sound.html) and/or a tutorial to load external sounds, for example:

[http://evolve.reintroducing.com/2008/01/10/as2-to-as3/as2-→-as3-loading-playing-external-sounds/](http://evolve.reintroducing.com/2008/01/10/as2-to-as3/as2-%E2%86%92-as3-loading-playing-external-sounds/)

Comment: I did the Sound class, and exported it as a .mov, which streamed in the audio just fine. I then used the Adobe Media Encoder to convert .mov to .flv and it worked perfect! Thx